# Increase size of font and window size in this Lua script

Tags: lua

This script renders a window with stats to the player as they play. Can someone help me increase the size of the window slightly and the font size? I have attempted a few parameters with no luck

I am adding more BS words here just so I can submit this post.

```
local messages = {}
local glitter = {}
local glitterCount = 0

function addMessage(text, mood)
  for i = math.min(#messages + 1, 4), 2, -1 do
    messages[i] = messages[i - 1]
    messages[i].targetPos = i
  end
  messages[1] = { text = text, age = 0, targetPos = 1, currentPos = 1, mood = mood }
  if mood == 1 then
    for i = 1, 60 do
      local dir = vec2(math.random() - 0.5, math.random() - 0.5)
      glitterCount = glitterCount + 1
      glitter[glitterCount] = { 
        color = rgbm.new(hsv(math.random() * 360, 1, 1):rgb(), 1), 
        pos = vec2(80, 140) + dir * vec2(40, 20),
        velocity = dir:normalize():scale(0.2 + math.random()),
        life = 0.5 + 0.5 * math.random()
      }
    end
  end
end

local function updateMessages(dt)
  comboColor = comboColor + dt * 10 * comboMeter
  if comboColor > 360 then comboColor = comboColor - 360 end
  for i = 1, #messages do
    local m = messages[i]
    m.age = m.age + dt
    m.currentPos = math.applyLag(m.currentPos, m.targetPos, 0.8, dt)
  end
  for i = glitterCount, 1, -1 do
    local g = glitter[i]
    g.pos:add(g.velocity)
    g.velocity.y = g.velocity.y + 0.02
    g.life = g.life - dt
    g.color.mult = math.saturate(g.life * 4)
    if g.life < 0 then
      if i < glitterCount then
        glitter[i] = glitter[glitterCount]
      end
      glitterCount = glitterCount - 1
    end
  end
  if comboMeter > 10 and math.random() > 0.98 then
    for i = 1, math.floor(comboMeter) do
      local dir = vec2(math.random() - 0.5, math.random() - 0.5)
      glitterCount = glitterCount + 1
      glitter[glitterCount] = { 
        color = rgbm.new(hsv(math.random() * 360, 1, 1):rgb(), 1), 
        pos = vec2(195, 75) + dir * vec2(40, 20),
        velocity = dir:normalize():scale(0.2 + math.random()),
        life = 0.5 + 0.5 * math.random()
      }
    end
  end
end

local speedWarning = 0
function script.drawUI()
  local uiState = ac.getUiState()
  updateMessages(uiState.dt)

  local speedRelative = math.saturate(math.floor(ac.getCarState(1).speedKmh) / requiredSpeed)
  speedWarning = math.applyLag(speedWarning, speedRelative < 1 and 1 or 0, 0.5, uiState.dt)

  local colorDark = rgbm(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1)
  local colorGrey = rgbm(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1)
  local colorAccent = rgbm.new(hsv(speedRelative * 120, 1, 1):rgb(), 1)
  local colorCombo = rgbm.new(hsv(comboColor, math.saturate(comboMeter / 10), 1):rgb(), math.saturate(comboMeter / 4))

  local function speedMeter(ref)
    ui.drawRectFilled(ref + vec2(0, -4), ref + vec2(180, 5), colorDark, 1)
    ui.drawLine(ref + vec2(0, -4), ref + vec2(0, 4), colorGrey, 1)
    ui.drawLine(ref + vec2(requiredSpeed, -4), ref + vec2(requiredSpeed, 4), colorGrey, 1)

    local speed = math.min(ac.getCarState(1).speedKmh, 180)
    if speed > 1 then
      ui.drawLine(ref + vec2(0, 0), ref + vec2(speed, 0), colorAccent, 4)
    end
  end

  ui.beginTransparentWindow('overtakeScore', vec2(uiState.windowSize.x * 0.5 - 600, 100), vec2(400, 400))
  ui.beginOutline()

  ui.pushStyleVar(ui.StyleVar.Alpha, 1 - speedWarning)
  ui.pushFont(ui.Font.Title)
  ui.text('Overtake Run')
  ui.popFont()
  ui.popStyleVar()
  ui.TextScaled(5)
  ui.TextSize(30)

  ui.pushFont(ui.Font.Huge)
  ui.text(totalScore .. ' pts')
  ui.sameLine(0, 40)
  ui.beginRotation()
  ui.textColored(math.ceil(comboMeter * 10) / 10 .. 'x', colorCombo)
  if comboMeter > 20 then
    ui.endRotation(math.sin(comboMeter / 180 * 3141.5) * 3 * math.lerpInvSat(comboMeter, 20, 30) + 90)
  end
  ui.popFont()
  ui.endOutline(rgbm(0, 0, 0, 0.3))
  
  ui.offsetCursorY(20)
  ui.pushFont(ui.Font.Title)
  local startPos = ui.getCursor()
  for i = 1, #messages do
    local m = messages[i]
    local f = math.saturate(4 - m.currentPos) * math.saturate(8 - m.age)
    ui.setCursor(startPos + vec2(20 + math.saturate(1 - m.age * 10) ^ 2 * 100, (m.currentPos - 1) * 30))
    ui.textColored(m.text, m.mood == 1 and rgbm(0, 1, 0, f) 
      or m.mood == -1 and rgbm(1, 0, 0, f) or rgbm(1, 1, 1, f))
  end
  for i = 1, glitterCount do
    local g = glitter[i]
    if g ~= nil then
      ui.drawLine(g.pos, g.pos + g.velocity * 4, g.color, 2)
    end
  end
  ui.popFont()
  ui.setCursor(startPos + vec2(0, 4 * 30))

  ui.pushStyleVar(ui.StyleVar.Alpha, speedWarning)
  ui.setCursorY(0)
  ui.pushFont(ui.Font.Main)
  ui.textColored('Keep speed above '..requiredSpeed..' km/h:', colorAccent)
  speedMeter(ui.getCursor() + vec2(-9, 4))
  ui.popFont()
  ui.popStyleVar()

  ui.endTransparentWindow()
end
```

Need font and possibly window size increased